# Смещения зоны загрузки drag-and-drop

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Зона загрузки `drag-and-drop` назначена на модальное окно. Когда заносишь файлы на зону, то зона сместилась в сторону.

Почему?! Необходимо над модальным окном.

[image: gif]

```
    function inputFile() {
        const dropPut = document.querySelector('.modal__window')
        const dropZone = document.querySelector('.modal__input-desc')
    
    dropPut.addEventListener('dragenter', (e) => {
        console.log('dragenter', )
        e.preventDefault()
        dropPut.classList.add('active')
      })
    
      dropPut.addEventListener('dragleave', (e) => {
        console.log('%cdragleave', 'color: red')
        e.preventDefault()
        dropPut.classList.remove('active')
      })
    
      dropPut.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
        console.log('%cdragover', 'color: lightgreen')
        e.preventDefault()
      })
    
      dropPut.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
        console.log('drop')
        e.preventDefault()
        dropPut.classList.remove('active')
      })
```

Comment: Проверьте, сколько у вас на странице объектов с классом modal__window.

Comment: Класс .modal__window на сайте в единственном числе.

Comment: Добрый день, есть возможность предоставить также файл стилей ?

Comment: [modal.scss](https://github.com/bgtvalex/Praxis/blob/main/src/scss/blocks/_modal.scss)